# In the windows terminal, can I start ubuntu from current directory while keep it starting from /home/$user/ if clicking the app directly?

Tags: command-line, windows, home-directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use the Windows subsystem for Linux ubuntu distribution in the Windows Terminal.

First I want to start the terminal from the current directory that I open in the file explorer. Therefore, I set `"startingDirectory": "."` in the `settings.json` following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1528644/981737). Then if I type `wt` in the address bar, Windows Terminal pops out and starts from the current folder, which is what I desire.

Next, I still want to keep the terminal opening from the `~` home directory when I directly open the app from start menu.

Is it possible to manage both things here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
ubuntu run bash
```